# HorizontalContentAlignment does not appear

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following code in my `.xaml`:

```
<StackPanel
         Orientation="Horizontal"
         DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="Yellow" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Margin="0,2,2,0"
         Name="MainButtonsPanel"
         Width="100" >
   <Button Name="ButtonSaveChanges" 
         Background="LightGray"
         Width="100"
         Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth}"
         Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
         CommandParameter="{Binding}" Visibility="Visible" />
     <Button Name="ButtonEdit" 
         Background="Gray"
         Width="100"
        Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth}"
        Command="{Binding MyCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
</StackPanel>
```

And it looks like this in runtime:

[image]

I want the gray squares to be aligned to the right. I tried with `VerticalContentAlignment`,  but it doesn't appear in my `.xaml` element when I write it...

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StackPanel has a property called as "FlowDirection".  Is this what you are looking for?

`<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Margin="0,2,2,0" Name="MainButtonsPanel" Width="400" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">`

[image]

Comment: Completely that... Thanks! So newbie... :P